# iOS Wi-Fi sync won't work in VirtualBox

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, wifi, ios

I am trying to set up Wi-Fi sync of my iPod Touch (iOS 5) with iTunes 10.5.0.142 running on Windows XP.

They sync fine over the USB cable. I've enabled Wi-Fi sync both on the iPod and in iTunes. The Wi-Fi is functioning and I can ping the Windows XP machine from the iPod. However, the Wi-Fi sync won't work (the sync app on the iPod doesn't see the computer).

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Notes:

1. Windows XP is running inside VirtualBox on Ubuntu.
2. I've checked out other similar questions, and none of them are relevant here.

Comment: Since this question has little to do with the iPod and iTunes and more to do with Ubuntu and Windows, it isn't really on topic for Ask Different. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanGreenstein: Whether or not this question gets closed makes no difference to me, except providing a disincentive to post again. However, for the record, it is clearly the Apple's products that are malfunctioning in a perfectly legit (if slightly obscure) setup. I therefore think the question has *everything* to do with this site.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have been able to figure this one out. In VirtualBox, select `Devices`/`Network Adapters`, and change `Attached to` from `NAT` to `Bridged Adapter`:

[image: VirtualBox preferences]

Click `OK`. Finally, reboot Windows and cold-restart the iPod.

This has fixed it for me.